# What is the difference between hyperplane and plane ? and why is hyperplane represented using eqn w^T+b=0 ?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, computational-geometry

I need a brief idea about SVM.So guys plz help to make me understand the representation of a hyperplane ? and the idea of kernel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the first part of @JeffHeaton 's answer is nice, the rest does not answet the OP question, so some further details:

#### formula

Why is hyperplane equation`w^Tx+b=0` ? First, you have to be aware what `w^Tx=<w,x>` does with `x`. it basically projects `x` (vector starting at (0,0)) at `w` (which is a vector starting in (0,0), so as the result, you can either get a positive number (angle between `x` and `w` is less than 90 degrees), equal to 0 (they are perpendicular) or negative (angle is bigger than 90 degrees). So you can see, that it equals 0 iff these two objects are perpendicular, so the only thing left is distance from the origin (0,0) which is done by adding a constant `b`. From the geometrical point of view `w` is so called "normal to the hyperplane", simply - a vector perpendicular to the hyperplane. So, if you now calculate `<w,x>` and get 0, x is perpendicular to the w, which is perpendicular to the hyperplane, so x lies in the hyperplane.

#### kernel

kernel, is nothing more than this scalar product `<w,x>` written in the previous formula. The only reason for writing `K(x,y)` instead, is that it assumes, that you have some "magical"mapping into some different space `phi`. In other words, if you have some function `phi` which rearanges your points in a way, that they are easier to classify, than you can train a linear svm on `phi(X), L`  instead of `X,L` (where L are correct labels). The problem is, that it is very hard to find a good `phi`. In practise, we simply choose a bir random or arbitrary `phi`, which simply maps points to higher dimension. This is a known mathematical fact, that in higher dimension, points are easier to separate. In particular, if you have N points `x_1, ..., x_N`, you can always select such `phi`, that `phi(x_i)=[0 0 0 ... 1 ... 0]`, where this `1` appears on the `i`th position. Unfortunately such`phi(X)` are expensive to calculate, and so we use a kernel functions instead, which is defined as `K(x,y)=<phi(x), phi(y)>`. So we do not have to know the explicit `phi` value, but instead, we just need to know the **scalar product between images of points through phi**. And this is exactly what kernels do, they denote scalar products in some differenct spaces. In particular, RBF kernel maps each point into ... FUNCTION (in fact, a gaussian distribution). So the `phi(x)` has an infinite dimension and cannot be efficiently calculated, but scalar product between two functions is just an integral of their multiplication, which is quite easy object.